# Plugin generated unexpected output - No PHP errors

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types, plugin-development

I'm creating a plugin that creates a custom post type I'm working on. I followed [this tutorial](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-guide-to-wordpress-custom-post-types-creation-display-and-meta-boxes--wp-27645). I have just changed it from movie_reviews to staff members. I don't get any syntax errors in PHP and it all looks alright, but when I activate the plugin in WordPress it says it generated 3 characters of unexpected output. I think the problem is the display_staff_member_meta_box function, but there doesn't appear to be any errors in it. Below is the code I'm using.

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Staff Members
Plugin URI: http://intranet.yourgroupuk.com
Description: Declares a plugin that will create a custom post type displaying staff members
Version: 1.0
Author: Harry Glozier
Author URI: http://intranet.yourgroupuk.com
*/

function create_staff_member() {
    register_post_type( 'staff_members',
        array(
            'labels' => array(
                'name' => 'Staff Members',
                'singular_name' => 'Staff Member',
                'add_new' => 'Add New',
                'add_new_item' => 'Add New Staff Member',
                'edit' => 'Edit',
                'edit_item' => 'Edit Staff Member',
                'new_item' => 'New Staff Member',
                'view' => 'View',
                'view_item' => 'View Staff Member',
                'search_items' => 'Search Staff Members',
                'not_found' => 'Staff Member not found',
                'not_found_in_trash' => 'No Staff Members found in Trash',
                'parent' => 'Parent Staff Member'
            ),

            'public' => true,
            'show_in_menu' => true,
            'menu_position' => 80,
            'supports' => array( 'title', 'editor', 'thumbnail', 'revisions' ),
            'menu_icon' => plugins_url( 'staff-icon-2.png', __FILE__ ),
            'exclude_from_search' => false,
            'has_archive' => true
        )
    );
}

function my_admin() {
    add_meta_box( 'staff_member_meta_box',
        'Staff Member Details',
        'display_staff_member_meta_box',
        'staff_members', 'normal', 'high'
    );
} 
?>

<?php
function display_staff_member_meta_box( $staff_member ) { //Causes error
    // Retrieve current Job Title and Company based on staff ID
    $job_title = esc_html( get_post_meta( $staff_member->ID, 'job_title', true ) );
    $company = esc_html( get_post_meta( $staff_member->ID, 'company', true ) );

    $table = <<<TEXT
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 100%">Job Title</td>
            <td><input type="text" size="80" name="staff_member_job_title" value="$job_title" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td style="width: 150px">Company</td>
            <td>
                <select style="width: 200px" name="staff_member_company">
                    <option value="Your Group">Your Group</option>
                    <option value="Your Power">Your Power</option>
                    <option value="Your Electrical">Your Electrical</option>
                    <option value="Newmills Engineering">Newmills Engineering</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
TEXT;
    echo $table;
} //End of function 
?>

<?php
function add_staff_member_fields( $staff_member_id, $staff_member ) {
    // Check post type for staff members
    if ( $staff_member->post_type == 'staff_members' ) {
        // Store data in post meta table if present in post data
        if ( isset( $_POST['staff_member_job_title'] ) && $_POST['staff_member_job_title'] != '' ) {
            update_post_meta( $staff_member_id, 'job_title', $_POST['staff_member_job_title'] );
        }
        if ( isset( $_POST['staff_member_company'] ) && $_POST['staff_member_company'] != '' ) {
            update_post_meta( $staff_member_id, 'company', $_POST['staff_member_company'] );
        }
    }
} 

/* function include_template_function( $template_path ) {
    if ( get_post_type() == 'staff_members' ) {
        if ( is_single() ) {
            // checks if the file exists in the theme first,
            // otherwise serve the file from the plugin
            if ( $theme_file = locate_template( array ( 'single-staff_members.php' ) ) ) {
                $template_path = $theme_file;
            } else {
                $template_path = plugin_dir_path( __FILE__ ) . '/single-staff_members.php';
            }
        }
    }
    return $template_path;
} */
?>

<?php
add_action( 'init', 'create_staff_member' );
add_action( 'admin_init', 'my_admin' );
add_action( 'save_post', 'add_staff_member_fields', 10, 2);
//add_filter( 'template_include', 'include_template_function', 1 );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The unexpected output is the blank lines betwen `?>` and `<?php`.

Avoid to close php tags and open them again with no reason. In your code, remove all the closing php tags (`?>`) and leave only the opening tag on first line.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was not aware that would cause a problem, I only did it like that as I did it one function at a time.